# How to get the value of the date in the HTML table and pass it to my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my code fetching the results in the table

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 
        '<tr>
            <td><center>'.$row['lname'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['outs'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['outw'].'</td>
            <td><center>'.$row['OT'].' HR/HRS</td>
            <td><center><input type="hidden" name="OT_date" value = "'.$row['OW'].'" id="'.$row['OW'].'" />"'.$row['OW'].'"</td>
            <td><center><input type = "button" name="btnedit" value = "APPROVE" id ="'.$row["id"].'" class = "searchbutton btn-primary view_data"></center></td>
            <td><center><input type = "button" name="btnapprove" value = "editortest" id ="'.$row["id"].'" class = "searchbutton btn-primary edit_data"></center></td>
        </tr>';
```

This is the JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
   var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
   var hiddenId = $("input[name='OT_date']").attr('value');
    var $otdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('value');
             $.ajax({  
                    url:"fetch.php",  
                    method:"post",  
                    data:{employee_id:employee_id},
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data){  
                    $('#name').val(data.lname);
                    $('#overtime').val(data.OT);
                    $('#OT_date').val(hiddenId);        
                    $('#employee_id').val(data.id); 
                    $('#overtimeModal').modal('show');
                }  
            });   
        }); // end of edit data function
```

This is the modal
[image: this is the modal]

This is the table
[image: this is the table]

I want to get the corresponding date in each row and pass it to the modal.. im using ajax.. i'm getting the right employeed id but not the correct date.. it appears that im only getting the first date.. 
I'm a fresh grad and wanting to develop my skills please help me..

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Comment: i'm sorry sir.. haha im not yelling.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you're having a problem wherein the date you get is always the same, no matter what record you edit.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
    var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $otdate= $row.find("input[name=OT_date]").attr('value');
         $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){  
                $('#name').val(data.lname);
                $('#overtime').val(data.OT);
                $('#OT_date').val($otdate);        
                $('#employee_id').val(data.id); 
                $('#overtimeModal').modal('show');
            }  
        });   
 });
```

i'm trying to understand here what you really want. i hope my guess is correct and helps you. btw, spend sometime reading jquery documentation since you're using it. the way i saw your problem is like you didn't even know the basic of jquery element selection

Comment: yes sir haha thats my problem.. thanks that you understand me..im having hard time to express myself.. and your very smart..you knew that im new in jquery..ill take what you've suggest to read jquery articles.. thanks a lot sir.. ill try this code and tell you if it works

Comment: thanks sir !! i'm getting now the corresponding dates.. but how can i pass it to my query in fetch.php ? just what i do in the employee_id? is that possible ?

Comment: the same way as you did to the employee_id. `{employee_id:employee_id, otdate: $otdate }`

Answer (score 0):

Put a dynamic class in your `<td>` for each date.

In PHP:

```
$class_counter = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo 
    "<tr>
        <td class='td_dynamic_classname'".$class_counter."><center>".$row['whatever_date']."</td>"
....";


//include a javascript in echo:
echo "<script>
    $('.td_dynamic_classname".$class_counter."').click(function(){
          // do something
    });
    </script>";
$class_counter++;
```